# Multiple elasticsearch sinks for a single flink pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My requirement is to send the data to a different ES sink (based on the data). Ex: If the data contains a particular info send it to sink1 else send it to sink2 etc(basically send it dynamically to any one sink based on the data). I also want to set parallelism separately for ES sink1, ES sink2, Es sink3 etc.

```
                                ->  Es sink1 (parallelism 4)
Kafka -> Map(Transformations)   ->  ES sink2 (parallelism 2)
                                ->  Es sink3 (parallelism 2)
```

Is there any simple way to achieve the above in flink ?

**My solution: (but not satisfied with it)**

I could come up with a solution but there are intermediate kafka topics which i write to (topic1,topic2,topic3) and then have separate pipelines for Essink1,Essink2 and ESsink3. I want to avoid writing to these intermediate kafka topics.

```
kafka -> Map(Transformations) -> Kafka topics (Insert into topic1,topic2,topic3 based on the data)

Kafka topic1 -> Essink1(parallelism 4)

Kafka topic2 -> Essink2(parallelism 2)

Kafka topic3 -> Essink3(parallelism 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ProcessFunction [1] with side outputs [2] to split the stream *n* ways, and then connect each side output stream to the appropriate sink. And then call `setParallelism()` [3] on each sink.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#the-processfunction
[2] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html
[3] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/parallel.html#operator-level